# How to maintain one database that can be consumed by an Android app and standalone app

Tags: java, android, database

I'm working on an Android app and a standalone POS system built using java for my university project,the project will be aimed at a fast food restaurant. The idea is:

Android app for customers - features:

1. sign in/sign up
2. View restaurant menu
3. Pre-order food, pay (using PayPal), send the order to the standalone POS at the restaurant so that when the customer arrives at the restaurant they can take away the food without an hassle.
4. Rate menu items.
5. Store preferences (Veg or non-veg dishes only shown, etc.).

Standalone POS - features:

1. Manager login/ Cashier login
2. Add, update or delete menu items
3. Handle transactions and print bill
4. Generate monthly sales reports

I need some insights on how to maintain one database to store all these details (with item images) which can be accessed by the Android app and the standalone app, should I use mySQL or any other DB?

Thanks!

Comment: use what cost you less in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check out [Firebase](https://www.firebase.com/).

I'll give a short list of Features provided by Firebase

1. Authentication (Email/Google/Twitter/Facebook and more)
2. Realtime Database (All the data is synced between all user devices accessing it)
3. Cloud Messaging
4. Storage Capabilities for storing images and retrieving them to the users device

There are many other features so i would recommend checking it out.

Comment: Interesting, haven't worked with firebase before but it looks promising. Will check it out, thanks!